# Android ImageView setImageBitmap

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, imageview, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to better understand how Android handle images in order to use memory more efficiently. I have an image stored in the `Bitmap` and I'm using `ImageView.setImageBitmap()` to display it. Now the question is - will it use the `Bitmap` I've passed it in the future, or it's making a copy of it and the `Bitmap` I've created isn't used anymore after the call to `setImageBitmap`?

Asuming it's gonna keep reference to the `Bitmap` I've passed, how is it gonna behave when `Bitmap` was created via `BitmapFactory` using `inPurgeable` option? Will `ImageView` prevent the `Bitmap` from being temporarily purged from the memory? Is it gonna happen only when `ImageView` has `View.VISIBLE` state, or also when `View.GONE` and `View.INVISIBLE`? Or maybe only while `ImageView` is visible on the screen?

And one more thing - looking through Android source code reveals that encoded byte data is always copied into memory (`inInputShareable` is currently ignored). Is it counted towards the 16/24MB memory limit for android Java application?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can answer some of your questions by simple experiments. I would say the bitmap you pass to setImageBitmap() is used directly. And, no matter if a view is gone or not, if it refers to it, it will never be destroyed by garbage collector. Pozdro ;)

Comment: Unfortunetely it's not that simple. Even if ImageView keep the reference to passed Bitmap, it doesn't mean that data stored in the Bitmap cannot be purged. According to the docs "resulting bitmap will allocate its pixels such that they can be purged if the system needs to reclaim memory", "when the pixels need to be accessed again(..), they will be automatically re-decoded". What I've asked about is whether ImageView will prevent the decoded data from being purged, or it will be purged and re-decoded when needed. There's no easy way to find out and it's behaviour can depend on several factors.

Comment: "when the pixels need to be accessed again(..), they will be automatically re-decoded"  - what if an ImageView has been set a bitmap as it was, created runtime, without any information where it was taken from. If that was true, it would be gone forever. I don't think so.

Comment: You're wrong again. When Bitmap is created via BitmapFactory using inPurgeable (and that's the case we're discussing), a copy of encoded data is also stored. I'm under impression you've forgot Bitmap is a complex class with lots of data, not a simple variable with decoded picture. Refer to the docs for further info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

There's some useful lessons that helps you to understand android's memory management better

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Well initially I was trying to leave a comment instead of an answer like this. However this site is seriously NOT friendly to new users at all, 50 reputation just for a comment? jeez